# What toolchain do I need to cross-compile Clang for iOS

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, arm, cross-compiling

OK, so first of all I know that this can be compiled on iOS (armv7) because I read the documentation. However, I can't find the right toolchain.

So, now, what toolchains I've already tried:

```
i686-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1
```

The above cross-compiles to x86 (I'm on i386). Works fine. But I don't need it

```
arm-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1
arm-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1
```

The above compiles fine, but doesn't cross compile to arm as I would have expected, instead, it simply compiles to my current arch.

I'm a real beginner in this matter, in fact this is my first attempt to cross-compile something.

UPDATE:

Here are the commands that I've tried(this is for armv6; armv7 is similar):

configure:

```
../llvm/configure --host=arm-apple-darwin6 --target=arm-apple-darwin6 
--build=i386-apple-darwin --enable-optimized --disable-debug  
--disable-expensive-checks --disable-doxygen  --disable-threads
```

env vars:

```
    export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS$IOS_BASE_SDK.sdk

export CFLAGS="-arch armv6 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -miphoneos-version-min=$IOS_DEPLOY_TGT -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/"

    export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1"
export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1"
export CXXCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1"
export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1"
export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
export AR=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar
export AS=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as
export NM=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/nm
export RANLIB=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib
export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/"

export CPPFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
```

UPDATE : The purpose of this cross compile is to make an armv7(armv6) library not a command line tool.

YET ANOTHER UPDATE: I used the following:

```
CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/clang"
CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/clang++"

./llvm/configure --host=i386-apple-darwin --target=armv7-apple-darwin --build=armv7-apple-darwin --enable-optimized --disable-debug --disable-expensive-checks --disable-doxygen  --disable-threads --enable-targets=arm
```

And I managed to get `checking whether we are cross compiling... yes` out of the `configure` tool. However, `make` still outputs a x86_64 binary:(

Comment: Just curious; what is the use of clang in an iOS app? Is the app an IDE for the iPad?

Comment: learning, testing, see if the ipad can handle it, it's purely academic.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal a collection of libraries then? I've edited the title, this way is better anyway...

Comment: @Valentin: No, it's a compiler front-end. You might call it an "application". Title is much better, thanks.

Comment: You can just look up the flags (-arch, -isysroot, ...) that Xcode sets for iOS targets and adjust them if needed. Keep in mind to use the compilers from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform etc.

Comment: Yes I know its a compiler front-end, but that describe its functionality. Anyway, I'm more interested on how can I cross compile it for iOS:D

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche I didn't tried it with xcode, but I did all the things you described manually (using the compilers from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform)

Comment: You should show us the actual commands that you've tried.

Comment: If you're using makefiles (not cmake), try running `configure` with `--host=your-host --target=armv7-apple-darwin`

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Question updated!

Comment: @SK-logic I get: `'Invalid configuration arm7-apple-darwin': machine `arm7-apple' not recognized'` seems like `arm-apple-darwin7` is the way to go

Comment: @Valentin, it's `armv7-apple-darwin`, please note `v` in `armv7`. The same triple should be used if you're bootstrapping Clang using Clang itself (and probably it is the best way to go with the iOS target). And your host is apparently wrong - you're obviously not compiling it on the iOS, it is likely to be `x86_64-apple-darwin` instead. llvm has a different notion of what the host is, you can't just copy a cross gcc configuration.

Comment: So, a command line should be something like: `CC=YOUR_CROSS_CC CXX=YOUR_CROSS_CXX $PATH_TO_LLVM/configure --enable-targets=arm --target=armv7-apple-darwin`

Comment: I don't know what Clang is(maybe it makes a good question on StackOverflow) :D. However, to clear things out, regarding how I intend to use it, indeed, I want to use Clang as a library, not as a command line tool. Will update question.

Comment: So, yes, **for me** it will (hopefully) be a library.

Comment: @SK-logic: Ah, sorry, I missed the `v`. Will try again.

Comment: @Valentin, running `make libs-only` would also help - last time I tried non of the llvm and clang tools could be properly compiled with iOS target.

Comment: @SK-logic: ok, so i tried `armv7` as you suggested and I got somewhere, both unfortunately the binary is still x86_64 :(

`configure:checking build system type... armv7-apple-darwin
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin
checking target system type... armv7-apple-darwin` which I think is correct

`make: checking build system type... armv7-apple-darwin
checking host system type... armv7-apple-darwin
checking target system type... armv7-apple-darwin`

Also, 'configure` said that we are cross-compiling and `make` said that we don't. I find this strange.

Comment: So basically, no matter what settings I use, I get a x86_64 binary :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention one important bit: you've got to run configure from some other directory, not the one where llvm is.

Comment: Yeah, I do that. The extra strange fact is that `Makefile.config` mentions the right arch and that we are cross-compiling. Will try to force load it (not just `make -j4` in the cwd)

Comment: @Valentin, there will be a number of host binaries compiled in the process as well - all under BuildTools directory (tblgen and the other stuff). Arm libraries will go under Release/lib/

Comment: @Valentin since you are using MacOS don't you have iOS development tools installed? you could then also use clang (that should be installed right?) to compile clang itself? are you compiling clang and llvm together or are you building them in separate?

Answer (score 1):

In principle your configure invocation looks good. I'm trying to shoot a few typical mistakes:

1. Did you `make clean` after every change of architecture?
2. Why are you so sure that the LD, RANLIB etc. of your host system are fine for cross-compilation? It will overwrite the auto-configured value of LD. (The line reading "export LD=ld" would be at fault here.)
3. Could you check a typical compiler and a typical linker invocation in the output of make for their correct use of the cross-compilation tools?

Comment: 1.Actually I didn't! Will try now. 2.
    Well, the Makefile script checks them, as far as I can see all's fine. On top of that, I use the same tools Xcode uses to cross-compile on iPhone.

    I find the make output quite confusing. At one point it says:

    checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking whether we are cross compiling... no

and then

 checking target architecture... ARM

Now, how the hell aren't we cross-compiling if the target arch is ARM and I'm on x86_64. Either the way, the result is x86_64. So yeah, we are **not** cross-compiling

Comment: To make things easier for you: The output "checking whether we are cross compiling... no" and all other "checking" lines are from configure, not from make :-).

Comment: I've just looked into my running cross-compilation build, and the test "checking whether we are cross compiling... no" tests whether executables produced by your compiler can run on the current system. If that's true, the test result is no. Should this be the case with ARM?

Comment: Actually, no, `make` also outputs that. Maybe it's invoking the `configure` script? Either the way, the outputs are different, when running `configure` I get "checking whether we are cross compiling... yes" and right after that, if I run `make` on the same dir I get "checking whether we are cross compiling... no". Even it it invokes the same script, I find that strange.

Comment: This is very strange and probably the source of the error. Can you log the whole output of make and tell when configure is re-executed?

Comment: Yeah, it should I'm on x86_64. So the make works fine? Still i'm using 'lipo' to test if the binary is arm and I get that it's x86_64 :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3697/discussion-between-thiton-and-valentin-radu)

Comment: @Valentin, yes, make invokes configure for building BuildTools. All the binaries under BuildTools should be your host binaries (i.e., x86_64).

Comment: @SK-logic Aha. That makes sense! No matter what I did, the output was the same in make

Comment: @ValentinRadu Did you find a working configuration? I read your chat discussion but I didn't quite follow.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Managed to build it on all possible archs except ARM

Comment: @ValentinRadu It seems you've asked this in the LLVMdev mailing list too. An Apple engineer suggested using the build_llvm script. (http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2011-September/043514.html) Which problems did you encounter when using this script?